# Merge two datatables?

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I want to merge two data table in which column "**ID**" as **primary key** in both table.

**Note:** Both table has two column as "**ID, Name**" & "**ID, name**" where Name & name is case sensitive.

**Table**: 1

[image]

**Table**: 2

[image]

**Expected** Merged Table Result:

[image]

Code:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Table 1
        DataTable table1 = new DataTable();
        table1.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
        table1.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(String));
        table1.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { table1.Columns["ID"] };
        table1.Rows.Add(1, "A");
        table1.Rows.Add(4, "D");
        table1.Rows.Add(5, "E");

        // Table 2
        DataTable table2 = new DataTable();
        table2.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
        table2.Columns.Add("name", typeof(String));
        table2.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { table2.Columns["ID"] };
        table2.Rows.Add(1, "A");
        table2.Rows.Add(2, "B");
        table2.Rows.Add(3, "C");
        table2.Rows.Add(5, "E");

        table1.Merge(table2);
    }
```

Please help me to achieve this expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could temporarily change the name of the second column and still use `Merge`:

```
const string OriginalName = "name";
const string TemporaryName = "temp";
table2.Columns[OriginalName].ColumnName = TemporaryName;
table1.Merge(table2);
table1.Columns[TemporaryName].ColumnName = OriginalName;
table2.Columns[TemporaryName].ColumnName = OriginalName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
DataTable dtResult = new DataTable();
dtResult.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
dtResult.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
dtResult.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));



var result = from dataRows1 in table1.AsEnumerable()
     join dataRows2 in table2.AsEnumerable()
     on dataRows1.Field<int>("ID") equals dataRows2.Field<int>("ID") 
     into rows
     from row in rows.DefaultIfEmpty()
     select dtResult.LoadDataRow(new object[]
     {
        dataRows1.Field<int>("ID"),
        dataRows1.Field<string>("Name"),
        dataRows2.Field<string>("name")
      }, false);
```